# JNA free memory allocated by shared library

Tags: java, c, memory-leaks, jna

I have the following functions in my C API:

```
MyStruct *create();
void destroy(MyStruct **s);
```

I map them by JNA to:

```
Pointer create();
void destroy(Pointer p);
```

I have a class that loads the shared library and uses these functions:

```
class MyClass{

    private mySharedLibrary library;
    private Pointer p;

    public MyClass(){
       this.library = (MySharedLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("mylibrary", MySharedLibrary.class);
       this.p = library.create();
    }
}
```

I don't know when and how to call the destroy function... Or shouldn't I call it at all?
There are no destructors in Java. Moreover, it get MyStrct** as an argument... What should I do?

Comment: Are you certain your `destroy` signature is correct?  It looks like it takes the address of the value returned by `create`, rather than the value itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should provide an explicit `destroy`, which you then invoke using the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) pattern.

If try-with-resources is not available to you, and for whatever reason do not use explicit cleanup, you can use a finalizer.  While these are not guaranteed to be run, in most cases it's probably good enough.

```
class MyClass {
    private Object finalizer = new Object {
        protected void finalize() {
            if (MyClass.this.p != null) {
                MyClass.this.library.destroy(MyClass.this.p);
                MyClass.this.p = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should test extensively within your own use case, to ensure that memory gets reclaimed according to your needs.